# draggable="true" preview hides children that are position:absolute?

Tags: html, css, position, draggable

Here is a demonstration:

- Top: child `<div>` **is** visible in the drag preview
- Bottom: child `<div>` is **not** visible in the drag preview

```css
.absolute {
  position: absolute;
}

.draggable {
  position: relative;
  height: 60px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  margin: 10px;
}

.draggable div {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;  
}

.left {
  background-color: blue;
}

.right {
  background-color: red;
}

.left.absolute {
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}

.right.absolute {
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
}

.right.float {
  float: right;
  margin: 10px;
}

.left.float {
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<!-- Expected behavior -->
<div class="draggable" draggable="true">
  <div class="left float">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="right float">&nbsp;</div>
</div>

<!-- Bug -->
<div class="draggable" draggable="true">
  <div class="left absolute">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="right absolute">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I see both working just fine.

Comment: I'm using Chrome Version 50.0.2661.86 (64-bit)

Comment: Seems to be an issue with Chrome 50: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=605119&can=2&start=0&num=100&q=draggable&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&groupby=&sort=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was [a known issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=605119&can=2&start=0&num=100&q=draggable&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&groupby=&sort=), now fixed.